# Error on host m/c - can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8888

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox, vagrant

Hi I'm learning django form kenneth love's GSWD video tutorials.

I'm using windows 7(32bit) and have vagrant and virtual box installed in it. The OS in virtual machine is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

As asked in the tutorial I did the following

> **vagrant@precise32:/vagrant/projects$ source ~/blog.venv/bin/activate
>
> Installed Django
>
> then created project with django-admin.py startproject microblog
>
> (blog.venv)vagrant@precise32:/vagrant/projects$ cd microblog
>
> (blog.venv)vagrant@precise32:/vagrant/projects/microblog$ python
>   manage.py runserver 0.0.
>   0.0:8000
>
> Validating models... 0 errors found Django version 1.4.4, using
>   settings 'microblog.settings' Development server is running at
>   (http removed)//0.0.0.0:8000/ Quit the server with CONTROL-C.**

After this when I go back to windows 7 browser and run 127.0.0.1:8888 as said in tutorial I get "can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8888" error.

What should I do to get the default "It Worked"-django page ???

Comment: how are you trying to run it in windows 7?

Comment: In firefox just typing the http address

Comment: Please help anyone ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change the Vagrantfile to do port forwardings?

For example, in your case, host port 8888 <=> guest port 8000

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8000, host: 8080
end
```

Refer to the docs: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html

Comment: Yup just did it. Same problem still persist.

Comment: Did you restart the vagrant server so the setting would take effect?

Comment: It worked Thanks a lot had to restart the vagrant server. Thanks a lot guys

Comment: If you don't restart the vagrant box, you'll have to figure out the running ID of the box and use VBoxManage to add the rule => `VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natpf1 "guestssh,tcp,,8080,,8888`.